# Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: /home/sbx_user1051/.m2/repository/webdriver

Tags: aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

While using WebDriverManager in AWS Lambda (Java) to have chrome driver, getting the exception 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: /home/sbx_user1051/.m2/repository/webdriver

I have tried setting the target argument for webdrivermanager
1. System.setProperty("wdm.targetPath", "/tmp/driver/binaries");
2.  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().targetPath("/tmp").setup();
Both ways not working.

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().targetPath("/tmp").setup();
webDriver = new  ChromeDriver(getLambdaChromeOptions(proxy));

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.2.1 is very old. Update to the latest one (e.g. 5.0.1) and try again.

Comment: If I upgrade, new errors come 
1. Only local connections are allowed.
2. [1559554537.037][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=97: Address family not supported by protocol (97) - This one come recursively